# Styling with nth-child

Tags: css, css-selectors

What I'm trying to accomplish is, the first two sections are white, followed by two grey sections, then that pattern continues.

I made a jsfiddle to show what I have so far: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u69rf/2/)

CSS:

```
section{
      float:left;
      width:40%;
      background:#ccc;
      padding:20px 25px;
      margin-bottom:2px
}
section:nth-child(even){
      margin-left:2px;
}
section:nth-child(1),
section:nth-child(2n+2){
      background:#fff;
}
```

HTML:

```
<section></section>
<section></section>
<section></section>
<section></section>
<section></section>
<section></section>
<section></section>
<section></section>
```

Would I need to use another `:nth-child()` to make this work correctly? Or would this be better to use jquery for?

PHP is being used to generate these boxes, so would a php approach be the best way? Maybe classes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nth-child is what you want, but what you're looking for is like this:

http://tinker.io/f5c5c

```
section:nth-child(4n+1),
section:nth-child(4n+2){
      /* styles here */

}
```

Comment: Perfect, just what I was looking for. Thank you for the response.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
section {
    float:left;
    width:40%;
    background:#fff;
    padding:20px 25px;
    margin-bottom:2px
}
section:nth-child(even) {
    margin-left:2px;
}
section:nth-child(4n),section:nth-child(4n-1) {
    background:#ccc;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/u69rf/7/)**

Comment: This also works the way I was looking for. Why would someone use the -1 rather than +1? The opposite effect?